# HandbrakeCLI unrecognized file type

Tags: batch-file, handbrakecli

I am trying to setup a simple batch file to use handbrake to compress videos. I had Handbrake installed and saw that I needed to install HandbrakeCLI separately. I downloaded `HandBrakeCLI.exe` and placed it on `C:\`. I then made a preset and set it as the default using the `GUI`. I then call `handbrake` like so:

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*.mpg) do (
    C:\HandBrakeCLI -i 'C:\Users\rv\Desktop\Newfolder\%%f' -o 'C:\encode\%%f.mp4'
)
pause
```

I get the following error telling me the file type is unrecognized:

```
[10:19:30] dvd: not a dvd - trying as a stream/file instead
[10:19:30] hb_stream_open: open 'C:\Users\rv\Desktop\Newfolder\126_812-714A_812-713_111914_san.mpg' 
failed
[10:19:30] scan: unrecognized file type
[10:19:30] libhb: scan thread found 0 valid title(s)
No title found.
```

Any thoughts on why the command line version is suddenly unable to open the file? The same file is able to be opened in the `GUI` and be converted.

I tried reinstalling everything and deleting the preset folder, even though that doesn't seem like the issue.

---

Update:
Here is the final code that works for me.

```
@echo off
set /A count_complete = 0
set /A count_total = 0
pushd %~dp0
for /R %%f in (*.mp2, *.mpg, *.vob, *.avi, *.wmv, *.mov, *.m4v, *.mpeg, *.mp4) do (
   set /A count_total+=1
)
for /R %%f in (*.mp4) do (
   echo Count is currently %count% of %count_total%
   C:\HandBrakeCLI --preset-import-gui C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\customencode.json -Z "CustomCompress" -i "%%f" -o "%%~dpf%%~nf_conv.mp4"
    if exist "%%~dpf%%~nf_conv.mp4" (
        del "%%f"
        ren "%%~dpf%%~nf_conv.mp4" "%%~nf.mp4"
        set /A count_complete+=1
    ) 
)
for /R %%f in (*.mp2, *.mpg, *.vob, *.avi, *.wmv, *.mov, *.m4v, *.mpeg) do (
   echo Count is currently %count% of %count_total%
   C:\HandBrakeCLI --preset-import-gui C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\customencode.json -Z "CustomCompress" -i "%%f" -o "%%~dpf%%~nf_conv.mp4"
    if exist "%%~dpf%%~nf_conv.mp4" (
        del "%%f"
        ren "%%~dpf%%~nf_conv.mp4" "%%~nf.mp4"
        set /A count_complete+=1
    )
)
popd
echo Count is: %count% out of %count_try% attempted.
pause
```

Comment: Where is the batch file located?

Comment: Batch file is located and run from the folder containing the videos, i.e. C:\Users\rv\Desktop\Newfolder\

Comment: You need to use double quotes, not single quotes. I would also change the output option to: `"C:\encode\%%~nf.mp4"`.  The tilde and n mean file name without extension.

Comment: Bah, you are right, it was the quotes. I'm embarrassed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use double quotes instead of single. Like this:

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*.mpg) do (
C:\HandBrakeCLI -i "C:\Users\rv\Desktop\Newfolder\%%f" -o "C:\encode\%%f.mp4"
)
pause
```